# What is the relevancy of the SQL Azure database size?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I upgraded from Basic to S0 Standard and that came with a default max. database size of 250 GB. I kept this max size, although my database is currently only 3 GB in size. Is this relevant for billing at all?

I guess the larger database size will only make a difference in billing once the database file is actually using the space on disk, but I am not sure about this. Maybe reserving the 250 GB will already cost extra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are billed based on the tier  you are in ,not by database size..Database Size is the feature of tier..You need not worry about unexpected costs.The only thing,that may vary from specified budget is  `Outbound data transfers`

Those Prices are also very nominal..

[image]

Comment: Good to know, thank you. I think Azure SQL pricing is quiet reasonable btw. (since if you use on premise instead you have quiet some administrative effort plus license costs), while I think that 55$/mo. for a not so powerful web/app server is overpriced.